# How to call Owin StartUp on an event?

Tags: c#, .net, owin

I was using owin startup class with Configuration(IAppBuilder app) method for AD login in my .net web forms application. I wan to give user a Button/hyperlink for AD authentication on existing login page only .I was facing issues in same . Can anyone please guide me on how i can achieve AD login on button click with owin startup or with any other method

Answer (score 0):

This is probably one of the best sources to start with:
[Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-asp-webapp)